# Agrupación de datos

Tags: mysql

Mi pregunta surge por un motivo de agrupación de datos de una consulta. Por ejemplo, requiero mostrar los datos de la siguiente forma en mi vista:

Actor: *Vin Diesel*

- Niñera a Prueba de balas
- Rapidos y Furiosos 1
- Rapidos y Furiosos 3
- Más...

Ciudad: Madrid

- Real Madrid
- Atlético de Madrid
- Rayo Vallecano

No tengo idea de como realizar la consulta para que me muestre los datos del `titulo`una sola vez y los detalles de cada titulo en concreto. Sin tener que realizar una consulta por cada sección y plasmandola en el HTML directamente.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Esto debe solucionarlo la vista, no la base de datos.

Comment: Estoy totalmente de acuerdo con @gbianchi, ahora si de todas formas necesitaras resolverlo desde SQL, te sugiero que armes un [mcve]. Saludos.

Comment: @gbianchi Pero como haria para traer un solo titulo sin que me traiga por ejemplo el Actor 4 veces en cada película? si pongo el titulo en la vista se verá como Vin Diesel Vin Diesel....

Comment: el actor va a venir en cada fila.. solo que tu vista tiene que mostrar una sola vez esa columna... y despues todas las filas, sin esa columna ;)